# Como utilizar sprintf para criar uma query com date_format()

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Estou reformulando um sistema de um cliente e o mesmo está usando o modo procedural no login e não PDO, porém para dar mais segurança, usei o `sprintf`, mas não está funcionando. Vejam:

```
$sql = sprintf(
    "SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(DataAcesso,'%d/%m/%Y') AS DataDeAcesso, 
    DATE_FORMAT(DataAcesso,'%H:%i') AS HoraDeAcesso 
    FROM loja_admin WHERE EmailAdmin = '%s' AND SenhaAdmin = '%s'",
    mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao, $loginUsuario), 
    mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao, $codificado)
);

$query = mysqli_query($this->conexao, $sql);
```

E quando dou um `echo` na variável `$sql`, não aparece nada. Porém quando tiro o `DATE_FORMAT()`, funciona. Teria algum meio de resolver isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver escapando o caracter `%`. Vejam:

```
$sql = sprintf(
    "SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(DataAcesso,'%%d/%%m/%%Y') AS DataDeAcesso, 
    DATE_FORMAT(DataAcesso,'%%H:%%i') AS HoraDeAcesso 
    FROM loja_admin WHERE EmailAdmin = '%s' AND SenhaAdmin = '%s'",
    mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao, $loginUsuario), 
    mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao, $codificado)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Estou reformulando um sistema de um cliente e o mesmo está usando o
>   modo procedural no login e não PDO, porém para dar mais segurança,
>   usei o sprintf, mas não está funcionando.

O uso ou não do `sprintf()`, PDO ou usar o modo procedural do `mysqli_*` não muda em nada a relação com a segurança do código.

O que realmente garante a segurança do código é você escapar os parâmetros da sua *query* com o `mysqli_real_escape_string()` ou então usar [*Prepared Statments*](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), que também estão disponíveis no PDO, mas podem ser usadas também na extensão do `mysqli` na forma procedural

```
$statment = mysqli_prepare(
    $this->conexao, 
    "SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(DataAcesso,'%d/%m/%Y') AS DataDeAcesso, 
    DATE_FORMAT(DataAcesso,'%H:%i') AS HoraDeAcesso 
    FROM loja_admin WHERE EmailAdmin = ? 
    AND SenhaAdmin = ?"
);

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $loginUsuario, $codificado);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Reveja a documentação desses métodos para mais detalhes.

[mysqli_prepare](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.prepare.php)

[mysqli_stmt_bind_param](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

[mysqli_stmt_execute](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-stmt.execute.php)

Comment: obrigado gmsantos. Vou dar uma olhada nas documentações.